Only collect partial of legends with patchwork
I am trying to only "collect" partial of legends with patchwork, below is a minimal example.
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = factor(vs))) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec, color = wt)) + geom_point()


(p1 | p2)/(p3 | p3 | p3) + patchwork::plot_layout(guides="collect") & theme(legend.position = "bottom")


The expectation is to keep the legend of p2 still at the bottom of p2, and collect and position the rest of legends at the bottom.
Thanks in advance.

One option would be to wrap p2 in wrap_elements where I additionally removed the plot.margin around p2 to still align the plot with the other plots:
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = factor(vs))) +
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec, color = wt)) +
  geom_point()


(p1 | wrap_elements(
  p2 + theme(plot.margin = margin())
)) / (p3 | p3 | p3) +
  patchwork::plot_layout(guides = "collect") &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")



Wow, @stefan! You are truly an expert on ggplot.
